# Using strtok to split the string and concatenating additional string - could it be done in a more efficient way?

Tags: c, string, split

I have a string `A,B` which needs to be modified to `Av1.0,Bv1.0`, where `1` and `0` are stored in respective variables `v1`, `v2`

I came up with a following logic but it seems a bit too verbose. Perhaps there's a better way around it?

```
void foo(char *str)
{
    char buff[100] = {0};
    int v1 = 1;
    int v2 = 0;
    char *first = strtok(str, ",");
    
    sprintf (buff, "%sv%d.%d,", first, v1, v2);
 
    int i = strlen(buff);
    
    first = strtok(NULL, ",");
    size_t len = strlen(first);
    
    strcat(&buff[i], first);
    i += len;
    sprintf (&buff[i], "v%d.%d", v1, v2);

    printf ("Final string = %s\n", buff);
}

int main() 
{
    char ptr[] = "A,B";
    foo(ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's error prone to pass a string to a function that gets munged as a side effect of what the function does. A production impl would not use `strtok` here, but since you asked...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// String s is destroyed!
void foo(char *buf, char *s) {
  char *pb = buf, *sep = "";
  for (char *ps = strtok(s, ","); ps; ps = strtok(NULL, ",")) {
    pb += sprintf(pb, "%s%sv1.0", sep, ps);
    sep = ",";
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char s[1000] = "A,B", buf[1000];
  foo(buf, s);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you mean by passing a string to a function that gets munged? your implementation passes `s` and so does mine. And ofcourse if `buf` needs to be accessed outside the function itself, it needs to be defined outside and be passed into a function that stuffs into it.

Comment: String s is an input. The call to stroke changes it by replacing separators. It's bad practice for any function to change its input.

Comment: your example modifies the input `s` as well so what's the point? Also your code is hard to read ngl

Comment: @xyf  Read the title. The point is that the OP asked for a more concise way to use `strtok`.  I did that and mentioned that in production you wouldn't use `strtok` to avoid mutating the input.  I'm sorry you find the code hard to read. It's a standard idiom for using `strtok` and string building. If you don't understand it, time for some study.

Comment: okay. It's just I thought your solution provided a solution for your argument about not modifying the input...